# Integral over $m$ dimensions down to $2$ dimensions

Tags: integration, orthogonality, substitution, gaussian-integral

In the supplemental material of [A machine learning paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3628-kernel-methods-for-deep-learning), the authors evaluate an integral over $m$ dimensions by converting it to an integral over two dimensions. The original integral to be evaluated is:

$$ k_n(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \mathbf{dw} \frac{e^{- \Vert \mathbf{w} \Vert^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} \Theta(\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{x})\Theta(\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{y})(\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x})^n (\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{y})^n, \ \ \ \  \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^m$$

and $\Theta$ is the heaviside (step) function. They provide the result in the main text:

$$ k_n(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \frac{1}{\pi} \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^n \Vert \mathbf{y} \Vert^n J_n(\theta),$$ with
$$ \theta = \cos^{-1}\Big( \frac{\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}}{ \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert \Vert \mathbf{y} \Vert} \Big),\\
J_n(\theta)=(-1)^n(\sin\theta)^{2n+1}\Big( \frac{1}{\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Big)^n\Big( \frac{\pi - \theta}{\sin \theta }\Big).$$

In the supplemental material they explain how the integral was evaluated:

> In this appendix, we show how to evaluate the multidimensional integral in eq. (1) for the arc-cosine
>   kernel. Let $\theta$ denote the angle between the inputs $\mathbf{x} \land \mathbf{y}$. Without loss of generality, we can take $\mathbf{x}$
>   to lie along the $w_1$ axis and y to lie in the $w_1w_2$ -plane. Integrating out the orthogonal coordinates
>   of the weight vector $\mathbf{w}$, we obtain the result in eq. (3) where $J_n(\theta)$ is the remaining integral:

$$ J_n(\theta)=\int dw_1dw_2e^{-0.5(w_1^2+w_2^2)}\Theta(w_1)\Theta(w_1\cos\theta+w_2\sin\theta)w_1^n(w_1\cos\theta+w_2\sin\theta)^n.$$

How does one interpret the quoted text geometrically? I'm having trouble understanding how $m$ dimensions can be reduced down to $2$ without loss of generality. Furthermore, what are $w_1$ and $w_2$? The authors do not explicitly describe their meaning. Can the integral simplification be explained in terms of a substitution (e.g. something like $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{w}=\Vert\mathbf{w}\Vert\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert\cos(\theta_{wx})=w_1$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $w_1$ and $w_2$ are simply the first two components of the vector $\mathbf{w}$ which you are integrating on. What the authors refer to as the orthogonal coordinates are the last $m-2$ components of $\mathbf{w}$.

Now, since the input for the function is only two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, we can always, without loss of generality, rotate our coordinates such that $\mathbf{x}$ lies along the first coordinate, that is,

$\mathbf{x} = (\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert,0,\ldots,0).$

Furthermore, we can now perform another rotation, as long as we leave the first coordinate unchanged, such that $\mathbf{y}$ is on the plane determined by the first and second coordinates, that is,

$\mathbf{y} = (\Vert \mathbf{y} \Vert \cos\theta ,\Vert \mathbf{y} \Vert \sin\theta,0,\ldots,0),$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.

Now, in our integral we integrate over an $m$-dimensional vector $\mathbf{w}$. However, since the integrand only depends on $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ through the scalar products $\mathbf{w\cdot x}$ and $\mathbf{w\cdot y}$, the last $m-2$ components of $\mathbf{w}$ are irrelevant; the scalar products do not care about the last $m-2$ components, since they are all zero for $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.

In other words, the reduction in dimensions follows from the fact that the integrals over each of the last $m-2$ components vanish and thus may be disregarded.

We have reduced the integral to an integral over only the first two components of $\mathbf{w}$, and thus

$\mathbf{w} = (w_1,w_2,0,\ldots,0).$

We can now easily calculate the scalar products and find

$\mathbf{w\cdot x} = \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert w_1,$

$\mathbf{w\cdot y} = \Vert \mathbf{y} \Vert (w_1 \cos\theta + w_2 \sin\theta),$

which lead to the solution presented in the paper.

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with orthogonality. Thanks!

Comment: I know that its been a while since you answered, but can we really always rotate our coordinates without loss of generality? What if the integral were, for example, over only the positive quadrant? Then when $\mathbf{x}$ is rotated $\mathbf{y}$ may be pointing outside the first positive quadrant? I'm not sure if that makes sense...

Comment: You are always free to parametrize the integration region (i.e., the range of values that $\mathbf{w}$ can take) using any coordinate system you like. In this case we chose coordinates which made the calculation significantly easier. Restricting to values of $\mathbf{w}$ in the positive quadrant already by itself requires a particular choice of coordinates to make the calculation feasible (can you see why?) and thus we are no longer free to choose coordinates based on the (arbitrary) values of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can see why. My guess would be that if we were to restrict the integral so that $\mathbf{w}$ only takes positive values and we still wanted to use the same method, we would have to assume that $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are also positive (and thus their angle is between $0$ and $\pi/2$) . Is that correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What we are rotating is not $\mathbf{x}$, which is given, but $\mathbf{w}$, which is the integration variable and thus we are free to parametrize it as we wish. However, if the components of $\mathbf{w}$ have to be positive, then we can't rotate $\mathbf{w}$ arbitrarily. The integral is then only invariant under transformations which preserve the positivity, such as scaling $\mathbf{w} \to \alpha\mathbf{w}$ where $\alpha>0$.

Comment: The relation between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ is actually irrelevant; the problem starts already with $\mathbf{x}$, since if I cannot rotate $\mathbf{w}$ such that $\mathbf{w\cdot x} = \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert w_1$, then I cannot simplify the integral.